# change the display of a JXDATEPICKER

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I used  a `JXDATEPICKER` in a `JFrame`. But, the date appears in the following form:
`ven.15/10/2014`

I want the date appears in the following format: `yyyy-mm-dd`
thanks.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.java.net/node/657164) link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf= new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-mm-dd" );
res = sf.format(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SimpleDateFormat to format the date in any desired format. Get the standard Date object from JXDatePicker.getDate() method, then use  SimpleDateFormat to get the date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date dateFrom = JXDatePicker.getDate();
String resultDateFrom = formatter.format(dateFrom);
```